# Stuck at editing XML file

Tags: c#, xml, nodes

first post here.. :D
so , I am stuck in editing my XML file and adding new nodes.
This is how my XML looks like:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Racuni>
    <------ I want to make new <racun> here with new data imported from list or at the end 
      <Racun>
        <datumkreiranjaracuna>20191230</datumkreiranjaracuna>
        <nazivulja>suncokretovo</nazivulja>
        <kolicinaulja>50</kolicinaulja>
        <cijenaulja>25</cijenaulja>
      </Racun>
    <------- or here :D
    </Racuni>
```

I want to add new `Racun` between `Racuni`  with new data from the list every time i open my console app. (it doesn't matter if it is before first `Racun` or after last `Racun`) I just want it to be saved there.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Is there a way to change specific `<cijenaulja>` ? 
I load whole xml document into a list, and then I want to change specific value in `<cijenaulja>thisvalue</cijenaulja>`
and then how do I save new value?

Comment: Could you edit your question and add the code you are having trouble with? So far it looks doable.

Comment: I only created file using XmlWriter, now I dont know how to load only the first part of XML, insert something , and then close it...
I can copy the code I used to create this Xml file if that would help

Comment: Edited with a new question, I am trying to edit that value when I load whole xml into list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Racun> racuni = new List<Racun>() {
                new Racun() { 
                    datumkreiranjaracuna = DateTime.Now,
                    nazivulja = "suncokretovo",
                    kolicinaulja = 50,
                    cijenaulja = 25
                },
                new Racun() { 
                    datumkreiranjaracuna = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
                    nazivulja = "suncokretovo",
                    kolicinaulja = 60,
                    cijenaulja = 30
                },
                new Racun() { 
                    datumkreiranjaracuna = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2),
                    nazivulja = "suncokretovo",
                    kolicinaulja = 70,
                    cijenaulja = 35
                }
            };

            string xmlIdent = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><Racuni></Racuni>";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlIdent);
            XElement xRacuni = doc.Root;

            foreach (Racun racun in racuni)
            {
                XElement newRacun = new XElement("Racun", new object[] {
                    new XElement("datumkreiranjaracuna", racun.datumkreiranjaracuna.ToString("yyyyMMdd")),
                    new XElement("nazivulja", racun.nazivulja),
                    new XElement("kolicinaulja", racun.kolicinaulja),
                    new XElement("cijenaulja", racun.cijenaulja)
                });
                xRacuni.Add(newRacun);
            }

            doc.Save(FILENAME);
        }
    }
    public class Racun
    {
        public DateTime datumkreiranjaracuna { get; set; }
        public string nazivulja { get; set; }
        public int kolicinaulja { get; set; }
        public int cijenaulja { get; set; }
    }
}
```

---

to add code to an existing file

```
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            XElement xRacuni = doc.Root;

            foreach (Racun racun in racuni)
            {
                XElement newRacun = new XElement("Racun", new object[] {
                    new XElement("datumkreiranjaracuna", racun.datumkreiranjaracuna.ToString("yyyyMMdd")),
                    new XElement("nazivulja", racun.nazivulja),
                    new XElement("kolicinaulja", racun.kolicinaulja),
                    new XElement("cijenaulja", racun.cijenaulja)
                });
                xRacuni.Add(newRacun);
            }

            doc.Save(FILENAME);
```

Comment: Thank you, it  created XML file. How do input more `Racun` into this .xml file?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should go with the `XmlDocument` because it is easier to work with tasks like this you described:

```
var xdoc = new XmlDocument();
    xdoc.LoadXml(@"
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
    <Racuni>
    <!-- I want to make new <racun> here with new data imported from list or at the end -->
      <Racun>
        <datumkreiranjaracuna>20191230</datumkreiranjaracuna>
        <nazivulja>suncokretovo</nazivulja>
        <kolicinaulja>50</kolicinaulja>
        <cijenaulja>25</cijenaulja>
      </Racun>
    <!-- or here :D -->
    </Racuni>");

// you must use the original XmlDocument to create new elements
var racun = xdoc.CreateElement("Racun");
var dat = xdoc.CreateElement("datumkreiranjaracuna");
    dat.InnerText = "20191230";
var naz = xdoc.CreateElement("nazivulja");
    naz.InnerText = "suncokretovo";
var kol = xdoc.CreateElement("kolicinaulja");
    naz.InnerText = "50";
var cij = xdoc.CreateElement("cijenaulja");
    naz.InnerText = "25";

// now, add the created nodes into the proper places
racun.AppendChild(dat);
racun.AppendChild(naz);
racun.AppendChild(kol);
racun.AppendChild(cij);

// finally, add the new element back into the xml document
//xdoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(racun);
xdoc.SelectSingleNode("/Racuni").AppendChild(racun);

// display the results
xdoc.Save(Console.Out);
```

You should also take a look in methods like `CreateAttribute` and also on know to locate a specific element using `XPath`.

Comment: I think adding new created element to `Racuni` elements children explicitly would be better. It assumes `Racuni` is the root level container and it may not be.

Comment: The problem is then, I need to change the code every time i open console app? Because xml document would change and I would have to edit what I load

Comment: if you need to persist your changes, you can save it to a file using the `save` method and load back that file using the `Load` method

Comment: So in          `xdoc.LoadXml` I can use path to my .Xml file?

Comment: @NikolaStjepanović, replace it with `xdoc.Load(path)`

Comment: Thank you! I have one more question, what is used to input variables such as etc. "a"  but that a equals etc. 5 instead of using `dat.Innertext`

Comment: Do not understand the question.

Comment: i want to use `dat.InnerText` to save data from list (list is connected to the structure) list name is : `iRacun` and structure name is `Racun`

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stackoverflow.

There are several ways how you could edit an XML from c#.

## XML Serializer

In the case you have the corresponding Models you could use the XMLSerializer to Deserialize the XML document, then use the resulting models to make your changes in the Data and then Serialize the models again.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer?view=netframework-4.8

## XPath

XPath is a type of Navigation that is "simular" to JQuery if your are familiar with that. It alowes you to load an xml document and then navigate into it and alter it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/xml/select-nodes-using-xpath-navigation

## XmlDocument

The XmlDocument is also the base of XPath but not limited to it. You can use its methods to navigate and manipulate the XML document and then save it again

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument?view=netframework-4.8